# Shopify api returns nothing when there really is data

Tags: python, api, rest, shopify, activeresource

Using the Python shopify API, I create a session and try to fetch all orders for a store. The code looks like this:

```
import shopify
import pprint
import logging

logger=logging.getLogger(__name__)

shopify.Session.setup(api_key=api_key, secret=api_secret)

session = shopify.Session(
    myshopify_domain, 
    api_version,
    access_token,
)

shopify.ShopifyResource.activate_session(session)

for order in shopify.Order.find():
    logger.info(pprint.pformat(order.to_dict()))
```

So shopify API clearly manages to create and use the session to fetch data successfully, as can be gandered from the log output:

```
2020-06-01 15:08:47 INFO (MainThread) [pyactiveresource.connection:257::_open()] - GET https://my-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json
2020-06-01 15:08:47 INFO (MainThread) [pyactiveresource.connection:301::_open()] - --> 200 OK 13b
```

However, the returned list of orders is empty (as is also evident by the "13b" in the log).

But when I look in the shopify admin panel for this development store, I have several orders of varying states and with varying data. There should be at least 4 of them submitted within the last week.

And if I just open the URL mentioned in the log https://my-store.myshopify.com/admin/api/2020-01/orders.json (not the real URL) directly in the browser, I also see a bunch of data there.

To me this raises a few questions:

- How come no orders are returned when using the api, even though it seemingly authenticates fine?
- How could I possibly get data when opening the URL in the browser since I have no authentication set up there?

Any hints are welcome. Thanks!

Comment: I'm not well versed in python, but I get around the Shopify API, so I'm shooting blindly. Have you request the `all_orders` scope for your app? This scope allows you get orders older than 30 days, if you don't have it will return the orders up to the 30th day from today. (it must be manually request from Shopify with a button on your App dashboard and waiting for Shopify approval of it)

Comment: drip actually I dont care about orders older than 30 days, and all the orders heve been verified to be newer than 30 days. I found the solution which is to pass the parameter "status=all". Apparently default is to only return open orders. Since all my orders were fulfilled then no orders were returned.